# How can read a table and insert differents values in another table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Before at all, I am quite newy in sql programming. I am trying to do a script that read rows from a table and insert those values (and another default values) in another table.

As far as I tried, this is my best shoot... :(

```
declare @pk_tercero_contacto int, @tercero_id int, @login nvarchar(200), @defecto bit, 
@descripcion nvarchar(200), @notificaciones bit, @tercero_usuario1 cursor

select @pk_tercero_contacto = max(t.tercero_id)  from TD_TERCERO_CONTACTO t
set @pk_tercero_contacto  = (@pk_tercero_contacto + 1)

declare tercero_usuario cursor FOR select t.LOGIN, t.TERCERO_ID, t.DEFECTO,
t.DESCRIPCION, t.NOTIFICACIONES from TD_TERCERO_USUARIO t

OPEN @tercero_usuario  
FETCH NEXT FROM tercero_usuario

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN 

select @tercero_id = t.tercero_id, @login = t.login, @defecto = t.defecto, 
@descripcion = t.descripcion, @notificaciones = t.notificaciones from 
@tercero_usuario t FETCH NEXT FROM tercero_usuario into @tercero_usuario1  

insert into TD_TERCERO_CONTACTO values(@pk_tercero_contacto, @login, null, null, 
@descripcion, @notificaciones, @tercero_id, null, null, null, @defecto)

set @pk_tercero_contacto = @pk_tercero_contacto + 1

END  

CLOSE tercero_usuario;  
DEALLOCATE tercero_usuario;  
GO
```

The idea is recover all files in a first table (5 column), then recover the five columns per each row, and insert those values plus default values in the second table...

I cant get it working

Thanks mates.

Comment: You are missing a  fetch in the loop

Comment: @paparazzo. It is in the first select inside de loop.

Comment: You might want to work on formatting

Comment: @paparazzo. Ok...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after researching a bit, and have tried a lot, I found the solution that I am posting for helping others in a similar case. Hoping it helps.

```
Declare @var1 nvarchar(200)
Declare @var2 int
Declare @var3 bit
Declare @var4 nvarchar(200)
Declare @var5 bit

        DECLARE cursor CURSOR FOR Select column1, column2, column3, column4, column5 from table1
        OPEN cursor
            FETCH NEXT FROM cursor INTO @var1, @var2, @var3, @var4, @var5
            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                BEGIN

                    Insert into table2 VALUES (@var2, @var1, null, null, 
                    @var3, @var4, null, null, null, @var5)

                FETCH NEXT FROM cursor INTO @var1, @var2, @var3, @var4, @var5
                END
        CLOSE cursor;
        DEALLOCATE cursor;
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is a sample format to insert selected rows from table1 to table 2 based on select condition.

I have edited query to suit your requirements to generate primary key manually for table 2

```
Declare @pk_StartIndex int

Set @pk_StartIndex = 79   --This is initial index that you will have to set 
manually, for each row returned in select query below the index value will 
be incremented by one

INSERT INTO table2 (PrimaryKey, column1, column2, column3)
    SELECT @pk_StartIndex + Row_Number() Over(Order By (Select 100)) 
    column1, column2, column3
    FROM table1
    WHERE condition
```

The Row_Number will help you generate numbers starting from Start Index provided.

in clause (Select 100) make sure number is sufficiently higher that the number of rows you expect select query to return

```
DECLARE @pk_tercero_contacto int

SELECT @pk_tercero_contacto = max(tercero_id)  FROM TD_TERCERO_CONTACTO 

INSERT INTO TD_TERCERO_CONTACTO (tercero_id, login, <your column name>, 
<your column name>, description, notificaciones, <your column name>, <your 
column name>, <your column name>, <your column name>,  defecto)

SELECT @pk_tercero_contacto + Row_Number() Over(Order By (Select 100)), 
t.login, null, null, t.description, t.notificaciones, t.tercero_id, null, 
null, null, t.defecto

FROM TD_TERCERO_USUARIO as t
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem is table2 has a pk not auto increment, so how you set this value? I declare a procedure where you get the max pk and increment it manually in the loop. Feel free for ask me whatever you need. Cheers.

Comment: I have made some changes, check if they work for you.

Comment: I could understand your answer. You are using pseudo-code and I need the sentences. Thanks mate.

Comment: Tried to modify it to suit to your table structure

Comment: I cant testing it until tomorrow, but I am voting up your answer just for your efford. Tomorrow I will try it and I will accept the answer if it worth...

Comment: I found a more elegant and efficient answer Pravin, I posted it. If you want to take a look.... Thanks my friend in any case.

Comment: Great, thanks for sharing. Please check though if using cursor is optimal solution in your case, as it is not generally recommended.

Comment: Thanks for your advice... If you believe my question or my answer or both could be useful for the community, please rate them with your vote. Best regards.